# ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX not working on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application using AJAX Extension 1.0. Every thing is working fine on WindowsXP (both development & production), but when I deploy my application on windows7 production server, AJAX stopped working. Controls in UpdatePanel are refreshing the page.

I have AJAXExtensionsToolbox.dll, System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll & System.Web.Extensions.dll in my application's bin folder.

I have tried installing the ASPAJAXExtSetup.msi (1.0), but it didn't worked.

I have also tried disabling the .net framework 3.5 from "Turn windows features on/off", but the problem was still unsolved.

I have also tried to fix the problem by changing some elements of web.config

**UPDATE:**

I am also getting JavaScript error on browser console "Sys is not defined". Is it realated to my problem?

Comment: Check the browser console to see the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

there is confilct between AJAXExtensionsToolbox and your JS code.
try to avoid using AJAXExtensionsToolbox because it is deprecated now.

the other thing check on the .net version that is installed in the server is it 3.5 or 4.5, i think 4.5 is not supporting AJAXExtensionsToolbox  any more